# Access - custom "was unable to append all data to table"?

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I created code for importing data from Excel into desired table, via TransferSheet and builded Query method. I'm also trying to resolve all errors that User could do when Importing data into db (wrong file format, appending 0 rows,field names not same as in DB etc.), but cannot get rid of Error 3059 "was unable to append all data to table" - It occurs when you try to Import some invalid data. I want a custom Msgbox for this error, and stop executing my Query. Here's my code - in short :

```
Private Sub CmdImport_Click()

Dim SQL As String

Dim dbs As DAO.Database

Set dbs = CurrentDb

On Error GoTo ERR1

DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acImport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12Xml, "NEWTABLE", "<Imported file>", True

SQL = " INSERT INTO MyTable (Field1)" & _
" SELECT DISTINCT" & _
" FROM NEWTABLE" 

DoCmd.SetWarnings False

dbs.Execute SQL

DoCmd.RunSQL "DELETE * FROM NEWTABLE"

DoCmd.SetWarnings True

ERR1:

If Err.Number = 3059 Then
MsgBox "This file doesn't have proper data to import. Import canceled !"
Exit Sub
End If

End Sub
```

This code pops-up custom Msgbox after Access allready opens built-in window, regardless of `DoCmd.SetWarnings False`. If I move `DoCmd.SetWarnings False` before TransferSheet method, import gets executed and no Msgbox is displayed - which is wrong. How can I handle this error, anybody knows ??

Comment: Looks like this one is hard rock. Still didn't find anything that might work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured out another way to solve this. I have put all controls that I need before DoCmd.TransferSheet method, including eliminating error that causes "was unable to append all data to table". I added code for checking excel file, and If Excel file data doesn't match criteria, DoCmd.TransferSheet is not performed - so therefore error "was unable to append all data to table" doesn't appear at all. Here It is (part of code which first checks If Excel file data is proper to perform DoCmd.TransferSheet import) :

```
 Dim XcelApp As Object

        Dim x, i
        Set XcelApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
        XcelApp.ScreenUpdating = False

        XcelApp.Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\Lucky\Desktop\Test\Sample.xlsx")

   With XcelApp

i = XcelApp.Rows(1).Find(What:="Število", LookIn:=xlValues, Lookat:=xlWhole).Column

x = XcelApp.Range(XcelApp.Cells(1, i), XcelApp.Cells(XcelApp.Rows.Count, i).End(xlUp)).Value

        For i = 2 To UBound(x)
            If Not IsNumeric(x(i, 1)) Then

            ExcelApp.Quit
            Set ExcelApp = Nothing
            MsgBox "This Excel file is not valid"
        : Exit Sub

            End If

        Next i

        End With

        XcelApp.Quit
        XcelApp = Nothing
```

Code is snapshop from this solved thread: [loop through Excel columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36176471/access-vba-loop-through-excel-columns)

Answer (score 0):

You could import to a temp table.

Then read this with a query that converts and cleans the data, and use this query for your further processing - which now will run without errors caused by malformed data.