# Access VBa - loop through Excel columns

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I'm having troubles with looping through Excel file from Access. Here is my code:

```
     Sub Xceltest()

        Dim XcelApp As Object
        Dim XcelBook As Excel.Workbook
        Dim x, i
        Set XcelApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
        XcelApp.ScreenUpdating = False

Set XcelBook = XcelApp.Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\Lucky\Desktop\Test\Sample.xlsx")

   With XcelBook

i = XcelApp.Rows(1).Find(What:="Število", LookIn:=xlValues, Lookat:=xlWhole).Column

x = XcelApp.Range(XcelApp.Cells(1, i), XcelApp.Cells(XcelApp.Rows.Count, i).End(xlUp)).Value

        For i = 2 To UBound(x)
            If Not IsNumeric(x(i, 1)) Then

            ExcelApp.Quit
            Set ExcelApp = Nothing
            MsgBox "This Excel file is not valid"
        : Exit Sub

            End If

        Next i

        End With

        XcelApp.Quit
        XcelApp = Nothing

        End Sub
```

Whatever I do, I always get an error in this line:

```
i = XcelApp.Rows(1).Find(What:="Število", LookIn:=xlValues, Lookat:=xlWhole).Column
```

or this one:

```
 For i = 2 To UBound(x)
```

Errors are "object doesn't support this property or method"  or "object variable or with block variable not set". How can I fix this, does anybody have a clue ??

Comment: You'd get the object variable error if the search value isn't found in that row.

Comment: But It is. in 1st row I have column named "Število". I forgot to mention - this code worked properly for 2 weeks, now suddently It doesn't...

Comment: Does: `i = XcelApp.Match("Število", XcelApp.Rows(1), 0)` work?

Comment: You are using latebinding? In that case you will also have to pass values for `xlValues` and `xlWhole`. Which is `-4163` and `1` respectively.

Comment: I would also recommend going through [THIS](http://www.siddharthrout.com/2011/07/14/find-and-findnext-in-excel-vba/) link on how to use `.Find`

Comment: @Rory,yes It looks like IT works, but then It stucks in next line, with declaring x.

Comment: @SiddharthRout,I have tried various methods before, I'll try this one too, but I had simmilar solution allready and It didn't work. Everything works in Excel, but not from Access.

Comment: That suggests that the text is not being found. Are you sure the correct sheet is active, and it's an exact match?

Comment: Yes, i'm sure. Data is only in Sheet1, nowhere else. And exact string is "Število", that is column name. I had simmilar problems before, when column names has dots (.) in their names - I figured that Access replaces dots with #. Is character "Š" in my column name maybe a problem ? Unfortunally, this character mustn't be changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have manged to get It working:

```
 Sub Xceltest()

        Dim XcelApp As Object

        Dim x, i
        Set XcelApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
        XcelApp.ScreenUpdating = False

        XcelApp.Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\Lucky\Desktop\Test\Sample.xlsx")

   With XcelApp

i = XcelApp.Rows(1).Find(What:="Število", LookIn:=xlValues, Lookat:=xlWhole).Column

x = XcelApp.Range(XcelApp.Cells(1, i), XcelApp.Cells(XcelApp.Rows.Count, i).End(xlUp)).Value

        For i = 2 To UBound(x)
            If Not IsNumeric(x(i, 1)) Then

            ExcelApp.Quit
            Set ExcelApp = Nothing
            MsgBox "This Excel file is not valid"
        : Exit Sub

            End If

        Next i

        End With

        XcelApp.Quit
        XcelApp = Nothing

        End Sub
```

I just had to remove ExcelBook from code, now It works fine.